# $\gamma$ is the straight line segment joining $0$ to $\pi - i \pi$. Evaluate: $\int_{\gamma} e^{\bar{z}} dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\gamma$ is the straight line segment joining $0$ to $\pi - i \pi$. I need to evaluate:
> $\int_{\gamma} e^{\bar{z}} dz$.

Is that correct?

$$\int_{\gamma} e^{\bar{z}} dz = \int_{0}^{1} \exp \left[ (\pi + i \pi)t \right] (\pi - i \pi)dt =$$
$$ =(\pi - i \pi) \int_{0}^{1} \exp \left[ (\pi + i \pi)t \right]dt = (\pi - i \pi) \int_{0}^{1} e^{(\pi + i \pi) t}dt = $$
$$ =(\pi - i \pi) \left[\frac{1}{\pi + i \pi} \cdot e^{(\pi + i \pi) t} \right]^{1}_{0} = (...) = (e^{\pi}+1)i$$

Comment: $dz=(\pi-i\pi)dt$ not $(\pi+i\pi)dt$.

Comment: Oh, ok. But only $dz$, right? Because in the $\exp$ function we got conjugate.

Comment: @geetha290krm excellent pun...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int \bar z dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150004/evaluate-int-bar-z-dz)

Comment: It is outside exponent

Comment: $e^{\pi t}(\cos \pi t + i\sin\pi t)$ in the last line.... you dropped the $i.$  You can proceed with integration by parts.  However, you don't have to work that hard... $(\pi -i\pi)\int_0^1 e^{(\pi+i\pi)t}\ dt = (\pi - i\pi) \frac {e^{(\pi+i\pi)t}}{\pi + i\pi}|_0^1$

Comment: It's done. I will update question. Can you check if it's ok? @DougM

Comment: But there can't be $t$ according to your last comment.

Comment: <Your last comment>$ = (\pi - i \pi)\left[\frac{e^{\pi + i \pi}}{\pi + i \pi} - \frac{1}{\pi + i \pi} \right] =(1- i)\left[\frac{e^{\pi + i \pi}}{1 + i} - \frac{1}{1 + i} \right] = \frac{-2i(-e^{\pi}-1)}{2} = (e^{\pi}+1)i$ @DougM

Comment: Sorry, no t... $\pi(1-i)(\frac {e^{\pi(1+i)t}}{\pi(1+i)})|_0^1 = (1-i)(\frac {e^{\pi(1+i)}-1}{1+i}) = (1-i)^2(\frac {e^{\pi(1+i)}-1}{(1+i)(1-i)}) =(-2i)(\frac {e^{\pi(1+i)}-1}{2}) = -i(e^{\pi(1+i)}-1) = i(1-e^{\pi(1+i)})$

Comment: So it's the same since $e^{\pi i} = -1$. Is that correct? @DougM